# Adjusting the scale of every plot in multiplot to be evenly spaced

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot multiple graphs using "multiplot" option from gnuplot.
The figure I plot was as below.

I have a small problem but I dont know how to solve this. The problem is regarding the scale of every individual plot. If one notice, scale for every plot a, b, c, d and e is different. For every plot I used different `set xrange` values. So, I understand gnuplot tried to stretched the plots to fit into the given width limit. Due to that, the scale along horizontal axis do not evenly spaced.

I want the scale to be evenly spaced for every plot especially for horizontal axis.

Below I have given the full code for your view.

How I can get this done?

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

########################################################################################

mpl_top    = 0.4 #inch  outer top margin, title goes here
mpl_bot    = 0.7 #inch  outer bottom margin, x label goes here
mpl_left   = 0.3 #inch  outer left margin, y label goes here    #vj
mpl_right  = 0.8 #inch  outer right margin, y2 label goes here  #vj
mpl_height = 1.0 #inch  height of individual plots
mpl_width  = 2.2 #inch  width of individual plots       #vj  
mpl_dx     = 0.1 #inch  inter-plot horizontal spacing
mpl_dy     = 0.4 #inch  inter-plot vertical spacing
mpl_ny     = 5   #number of rows
mpl_nx     = 1   #number of columns

# calculate full dimensions
xsize = mpl_left+mpl_right+(mpl_width*mpl_nx)+(mpl_nx-1)*mpl_dx
ysize = mpl_top+mpl_bot+(mpl_ny*mpl_height)+(mpl_ny-1)*mpl_dy

# placement functions
#   rows are numbered from bottom to top
bot(n) = (mpl_bot+(n-1)*mpl_height+(n-1)*mpl_dy)/ysize
top(n)  = 1-((mpl_top+(mpl_ny-n)*(mpl_height+mpl_dy))/ysize)
#   columns are numbered from left to right
left(n) = (mpl_left+(n-1)*mpl_width+(n-1)*mpl_dx)/xsize
right(n)  = 1-((mpl_right+(mpl_nx-n)*(mpl_width+mpl_dx))/xsize)

#=================================================================

#set terminal postscript eps enhanced color dl 2.0 size xsize,ysize "Helvetica" 28
##set encoding iso_8859_1
##set tics scale 1
#set output 'nxm_plot.eps'


set terminal pngcairo size 650,650 enhanced dash #font "Arial-Bold,13" #fontscale 1.20
set output "Fill-Multi-plot-LDP-lyoSystemLast50ns.png"

set encoding iso_8859_1

set offsets
set autoscale fix
set size 1,1
set nokey

# define x-axis settings for all subplots
#set xrange [-30:30]
set yrange [0:3]
set xlabel ''
#set format x ''
set xtic auto
#set xtics 5    #pi
#set mxtics 4


#### VJ DEFINITION
#set style line 4 lt 4 lw 10    # Please DISABLE pause -1 
#########################################################################################

set style line 1 lt 1 lw 1.5  lc rgb "red"
set style line 2 lt 3 lw 1.5  lc rgb "red"
set style line 3 lt 5 lw 1.5  lc rgb "red"

set style line 4 lt 1 lw 1.5  lc rgb "black"
set style line 5 lt 3 lw 1.5  lc rgb "black"
set style line 6 lt 5 lw 1.5  lc rgb "black"

set style line 7 lt 1 lw 1.5  lc rgb "green"
set style line 8 lt 3 lw 1.5  lc rgb "green"
set style line 9 lt 5 lw 1.5  lc rgb "green"

set style line 10 lt 1 lw 1.5  lc rgb "blue"
set style line 11 lt 3 lw 1.5  lc rgb "blue"
set style line 12 lt 5 lw 1.5  lc rgb "blue"

set style line 13 lt 1 lw 1.5  lc rgb "magenta"
set style line 14 lt 3 lw 1.5  lc rgb "magenta"
set style line 15 lt 5 lw 1.5  lc rgb "magenta"

set style line 16 lt 1 lw 1.5  lc rgb "#6495ED"
set style line 17 lt 3 lw 1.5  lc rgb "#6495ED"
set style line 18 lt 5 lw 1.5  lc rgb "#6495ED"

###################################################################################################
set macro
#ylabelFONT="font 'arial,16'"
labelFONT="font 'Arial,16'"
scaleFONT="font 'Arial-Bold,14'"
scaleFONtt="font 'Helvetica,10'"
keyFONT="font 'Arial,12'"
#graph="using 1:2 with lines lw 1 "

###################################################################################################


# start plotting
set multiplot

#-----------------------------------------------
# subplot  1-5
#  set horizontal margins for first column
set lmargin at screen left(1)
set rmargin at screen right(1)
#  set horizontal margins for third row (top)
set tmargin at screen top(5)
set bmargin at screen bot(5)


set label "(a)" at -1.5,2.5  @labelFONT
set title ''
unset ylabel
set xrange [-20.0:20.0]
set format y "" #"%-2.1f"
plot    "malto12per-000-050ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '1-050ns'  w  l  ls  1  ,\
        "malto12per-000-050ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '1-050ns'  w  l  ls  2  ,\
    "malto12per-000-050ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '1-050ns'  w  l  ls  3  ,\
    "malto12per-051-100ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '51-100ns'  w  l  ls  4  ,\
    "malto12per-051-100ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '51-100ns'  w  l  ls  5  ,\
    "malto12per-051-100ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '51-100ns'  w  l  ls  6  ,\
    "malto12per-101-150ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '101-150ns'  w  l  ls  7  ,\
    "malto12per-101-150ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '101-150ns'  w  l  ls  8  ,\
    "malto12per-101-150ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '101-150ns'  w  l  ls  9  ,\
    "malto12per-151-200ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '151-200ns'  w  l  ls  10 ,\
    "malto12per-151-200ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '151-200ns'  w  l  ls  11 ,\
    "malto12per-151-200ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '151-200ns'  w  l  ls  12 ,\
    "malto12per-201-250ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '201-250ns'  w  l  ls  13 ,\
    "malto12per-201-250ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '201-250ns'  w  l  ls  14 ,\
    "malto12per-201-250ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '201-250ns'  w  l  ls  15 ,\
    "malto12per-251-300ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '251-300ns'  w  l  ls  16 ,\
    "malto12per-251-300ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '251-300ns'  w  l  ls  17 ,\
    "malto12per-251-300ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '251-300ns'  w  l  ls  18 
;


#-----------------------------------------------
# subplot  1-4 at top most
#  set horizontal margins for first column
set lmargin at screen left(1)
set rmargin at screen right(1)
#  set horizontal margins for third row (top)
set tmargin at screen top(4)
set bmargin at screen bot(4)


unset label
set label "(b)" at -1.5,2.5  @labelFONT
set title ''
unset ylabel
set xtics
set xrange [-26.2:26.2]
set format y "" #"%-2.1f"


plot    "malto23per-000-050ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '1-050ns'  w  l  ls  1  ,\
        "malto23per-000-050ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '1-050ns'  w  l  ls  2  ,\
        "malto23per-000-050ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '1-050ns'  w  l  ls  3  ,\
        "malto23per-051-100ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '51-100ns'  w  l  ls  4  ,\
        "malto23per-051-100ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '51-100ns'  w  l  ls  5  ,\
        "malto23per-051-100ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '51-100ns'  w  l  ls  6  ,\
        "malto23per-101-150ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '101-150ns'  w  l  ls  7  ,\
        "malto23per-101-150ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '101-150ns'  w  l  ls  8  ,\
        "malto23per-101-150ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '101-150ns'  w  l  ls  9  ,\
        "malto23per-151-200ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '151-200ns'  w  l  ls  10 ,\
        "malto23per-151-200ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '151-200ns'  w  l  ls  11 ,\
        "malto23per-151-200ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '151-200ns'  w  l  ls  12 ,\
        "malto23per-201-250ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '201-250ns'  w  l  ls  13 ,\
        "malto23per-201-250ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '201-250ns'  w  l  ls  14 ,\
        "malto23per-201-250ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '201-250ns'  w  l  ls  15 ,\
        "malto23per-251-300ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '251-300ns'  w  l  ls  16 ,\
        "malto23per-251-300ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '251-300ns'  w  l  ls  17 ,\
        "malto23per-251-300ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '251-300ns'  w  l  ls  18
;


#-----------------------------------------------
# subplot  1-3
#  set horizontal margins for first column
set lmargin at screen left(1)
set rmargin at screen right(1)
#  set horizontal margins for second row (middle)
set tmargin at screen top(3)
set bmargin at screen bot(3)


unset label
set label "(c)" at -1.5,2.5  @labelFONT
set title ''
set ylabel "Number Density" @labelFONT
set xrange [-24.2:24.2]
set format y "" #"%-1.1f"
plot    "bcm25perR-000-050ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '1-050ns'  w  l  ls  1  ,\
        "bcm25perR-000-050ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '1-050ns'  w  l  ls  2  ,\
        "bcm25perR-000-050ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '1-050ns'  w  l  ls  3  ,\
        "bcm25perR-051-100ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '51-100ns'  w  l  ls  4  ,\
        "bcm25perR-051-100ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '51-100ns'  w  l  ls  5  ,\
        "bcm25perR-051-100ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '51-100ns'  w  l  ls  6  ,\
        "bcm25perR-101-150ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '101-150ns'  w  l  ls  7  ,\
        "bcm25perR-101-150ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '101-150ns'  w  l  ls  8  ,\
        "bcm25perR-101-150ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '101-150ns'  w  l  ls  9  ,\
        "bcm25perR-151-200ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '151-200ns'  w  l  ls  10 ,\
        "bcm25perR-151-200ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '151-200ns'  w  l  ls  11 ,\
        "bcm25perR-151-200ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '151-200ns'  w  l  ls  12 ,\
        "bcm25perR-201-250ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '201-250ns'  w  l  ls  13 ,\
        "bcm25perR-201-250ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '201-250ns'  w  l  ls  14 ,\
        "bcm25perR-201-250ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '201-250ns'  w  l  ls  15 ,\
        "bcm25perR-251-300ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '251-300ns'  w  l  ls  16 ,\
        "bcm25perR-251-300ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '251-300ns'  w  l  ls  17 ,\
        "bcm25perR-251-300ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '251-300ns'  w  l  ls  18
;



#-----------------------------------------------
# subplot  1-2
#  set horizontal margins for first column
set lmargin at screen left(1)
set rmargin at screen right(1)
#  set horizontal margins for second row (middle)
set tmargin at screen top(2)
set bmargin at screen bot(2)


unset label
set label "(d)" at -1.5,2.5  @labelFONT
set title ''
unset ylabel
set xrange [-24.8:24.8]
set format y "" #"%-1.1f"
plot    "bcm25perS-000-050ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '1-050ns'  w  l  ls  1  ,\
        "bcm25perS-000-050ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '1-050ns'  w  l  ls  2  ,\
        "bcm25perS-000-050ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '1-050ns'  w  l  ls  3  ,\
        "bcm25perS-051-100ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '51-100ns'  w  l  ls  4  ,\
        "bcm25perS-051-100ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '51-100ns'  w  l  ls  5  ,\
        "bcm25perS-051-100ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '51-100ns'  w  l  ls  6  ,\
        "bcm25perS-101-150ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '101-150ns'  w  l  ls  7  ,\
        "bcm25perS-101-150ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '101-150ns'  w  l  ls  8  ,\
        "bcm25perS-101-150ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '101-150ns'  w  l  ls  9  ,\
        "bcm25perS-151-200ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '151-200ns'  w  l  ls  10 ,\
        "bcm25perS-151-200ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '151-200ns'  w  l  ls  11 ,\
        "bcm25perS-151-200ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '151-200ns'  w  l  ls  12 ,\
        "bcm25perS-201-250ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '201-250ns'  w  l  ls  13 ,\
        "bcm25perS-201-250ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '201-250ns'  w  l  ls  14 ,\
        "bcm25perS-201-250ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '201-250ns'  w  l  ls  15 ,\
        "bcm25perS-251-300ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '251-300ns'  w  l  ls  16 ,\
        "bcm25perS-251-300ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '251-300ns'  w  l  ls  17 ,\
        "bcm25perS-251-300ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '251-300ns'  w  l  ls  18
;


#-----------------------------------------------
# subplot  1-1
#  set horizontal margins for first column
set lmargin at screen left(1)
set rmargin at screen right(1)
#  set horizontal margins for first row (bottom)
set tmargin at screen top(1)
set bmargin at screen bot(1)


unset label
set label "(e)" at -1.5,2.5  @labelFONT
set title ''
# now set a label and tic marks for the x-axis
set xlabel "Distance / ({\305})"    @labelFONT
unset ylabel
set xrange [-24.1:24.1]
set format y "" # "%-1.1f"

plot    "bcm25perRS-000-050ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '1-050ns'  w  l  ls  1  ,\
        "bcm25perRS-000-050ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '1-050ns'  w  l  ls  2  ,\
        "bcm25perRS-000-050ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '1-050ns'  w  l  ls  3  ,\
        "bcm25perRS-051-100ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '51-100ns'  w  l  ls  4  ,\
        "bcm25perRS-051-100ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '51-100ns'  w  l  ls  5  ,\
        "bcm25perRS-051-100ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '51-100ns'  w  l  ls  6  ,\
        "bcm25perRS-101-150ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '101-150ns'  w  l  ls  7  ,\
        "bcm25perRS-101-150ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '101-150ns'  w  l  ls  8  ,\
        "bcm25perRS-101-150ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '101-150ns'  w  l  ls  9  ,\
        "bcm25perRS-151-200ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '151-200ns'  w  l  ls  10 ,\
        "bcm25perRS-151-200ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '151-200ns'  w  l  ls  11 ,\
        "bcm25perRS-151-200ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '151-200ns'  w  l  ls  12 ,\
        "bcm25perRS-201-250ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '201-250ns'  w  l  ls  13 ,\
        "bcm25perRS-201-250ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '201-250ns'  w  l  ls  14 ,\
        "bcm25perRS-201-250ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '201-250ns'  w  l  ls  15 ,\
        "bcm25perRS-251-300ns_only_HEAD.dat"       using 1:2 title  '251-300ns'  w  l  ls  16 ,\
        "bcm25perRS-251-300ns_only_TAIL.dat"       using 1:2 title  '251-300ns'  w  l  ls  17 ,\
        "bcm25perRS-251-300ns_only_WATER.dat"      using 1:2 title  '251-300ns'  w  l  ls  18
;

#----------------------------------------------------
set size 0.3,0.5
set origin -0.56,-0.35
set bmargin at screen 0
#set key at screen 0.85,screen 0.45 Left reverse spacing 1.0 samplen 1.0 maxcols 1 maxrows 6 @keyFONT
set key at screen 1.00,screen 0.45 maxcols 3 maxrows 6 @keyFONT
#set key center left  
set border 0 
unset xlabel
unset ylabel
unset label
unset tics
set format x ""
set format y ""
set yrange [0:1]
plot 2 ls 1 t '1-50ns', \
     2 ls 4 t '51-100ns', \
     2 ls 7 t '101-150ns', \
     2 ls 10    t '151-200ns', \
     2 ls 13    t '201-250ns', \
     2 ls 16    t '251-300ns'
;

unset multiplot
```

Comment: Please add a *minimal* working example that reproduces your problem. It increases the chances that someone will take the time to go through your code.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you want the units to have the same length for all graphs. You can dynamically set the margins to obtain this effect with a `do` loop. Basically you'll need to define the xranges at the beginning and also the maximum range that you will find (you could do this also automatically with a bit more work). The following code should do what you want (read the comments for further info):

```
# This function returns the ranges for each graph,
# I have only defined 3
range(i)=(i == 1 ? "-20 20" : \
          i == 2 ? "-25 25" : \
          i == 3 ? "-15 15" : 1/0)

# Number of graphs and maxrange
N = 3; maxrange = 50.

set xtics 5.

set multiplot

# Loop
do for [i=1:N] {
# Set the margins
set tmargin at screen 0.98-(i-1.)/N
set bmargin at screen 0.74-(i-1.)/N
# Set range and calculate total range for graph i
set xrange [word(range(i),1) : word(range(i),2)]
totalrange = word(range(i),2) - word(range(i),1)
# Center the graphs at 0.55 and scale them depending on their range
set lmargin at screen 0.55-0.43*totalrange/maxrange
set rmargin at screen 0.55+0.43*totalrange/maxrange
# Plot
plot sin(x) not
}
```

[image]

Of course there is room for plenty of customization here.

You can define your functions also depending on the label `i` so they change through the loop:

```
f(x,i) = (i == 1 ? sin(x) : \
          i == 2 ? cos(x) : \
          i == 3 ? tan(x) : 1/0)
.
.
.
plot f(x,i)
```

If you have data files, you can do the same in this way:

```
datafiles = "data1 data2 data3"
.
.
.
plot word(datafiles,i)
```

Likewise with the styles and so on:

```
set style line 1 lw 1
set style line 2 lw 2
set style line 3 lw 3
.
.
.
plot f(x,i) ls i
```

Finally, if you want complete control (e.g. you are mixing functions and datafile or something else) you can define `if` statements within the for loop:

```
.
.
.
if (i == 1) {plot sin(x)}
if (i == 2) {plot cos(x)}
if (i == 3) {plot "data1"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I encounter this for the first time. Well, in this example all the three graphs plot the same function. How about for different functions in the loop, like cos(x), sin(x) and tan(x)?

Comment: Dear Miguel, In my case can I define the range for each graph separately? For that do I need to define the range like this - ( range(1)=( 1 ? "-20 20" : \   )? What is the meaning of 1/0 ?

Comment: `i` is just a label to change some option through the loop. To change the range just edit the first part of my code. To change the function you can try something similar: `f(x,i) = (i == 1 ? sin(x) : i == 2 ? cos(x) : 1/0)`. The 1/0 tells gnuplot to ignore the function and in my example it's returned if i is not 1 or 2 or 3.